# How to load a .tar.gz into QGIS

Tags: qgis

I've got a file that I'd like to load into QGIS. It's format is .tar.gz, but I can't really find how to load this in online and since I'm fairly inexperienced I've never seen this extension before. How does one go about putting this on QGIS?

Comment: Have you considered conducting an online search for this extension?

Answer (score 6):

A tar.gz file is a compressed file. You can't open it with QGIS. You should first uncompress it with a software like 7-Zip (for Windows). Then you will have the content of the compressed file, and perhaps it will be compatible with QGIS.